# Can't get Window 1 of process intermittently thrown

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript saved as an always on application, which generally works. However, there are odd instances where it will throw the error:
*"Systems Events got an error: Can't get window 1 of process "FaceTime". Invalid index. (-1719)"*
Mostly occurs if FaceTime app is closed, but not always. Odd.

Can anyone advise how I can dismiss this or write better code to avoid?

Here is my code:

```
on idle
if application "FaceTime" is running then
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "FaceTime"
            if get value of attribute "axFullScreen" of window 1 = false then
                set FullscreenButton to a reference to (button "Full Screen" of window 1)
                if FullscreenButton exists then
                    click FullscreenButton
                end if
            end if
        end tell

    end tell
end if
return 3
```

end idle

on quit
    continue quit
end quit

Comment: Just after the "tell process face time", add a line to test if the (count of windows) >0 then do your stuff. else, it means no window open, then your script will do nothing, but no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all Code inside the idle block in a try and Error Block. If an error is thrown itll be catched

```
try 
    -- your code 
on error err 
    log err
end try
```